# If some sentence has truth, could it be called sarcasm

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english

**Never lie to someone who trusts you; never trust someone who lies to you**
Could this be called a sarcastic remark?
Especially if I send this quote to someone who lies a lot?
If I send this to someone who lies, there is truth. Will it be correct to call it sarcasm?
I am somewhat confused about the word sarcasm, which means saying something in an insulting way. But the above quote could be insulting to a person who lies to a severe level.
So it's not just insulting someone but also conveying the truth.
Or maybe there is some other word than sarcasm that is more appropriate

Comment: Sarcasm is not inherently insulting. It is stating the opposite of what you blatantly mean. It can be done as an insult, but it is not only used as an insult.

Comment: @rohit What is your goal with this question? It seems you aren't interested in the definition of "sarcasm". Are you looking for a word to describe the action of telling someone you know they're a liar by sending them a quote like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Sarcasm is when you say something, but mean the opposite, for humorous effect, in order to mock/criticise or poke fun at someone. It's not always intended as an insult, although it could be perceived that way.

If you wanted to use sarcasm in the situation you described, you could say

> I obviously believe every single word you say.

This could be said with a mocking tone, perhaps with raised eyebrows, a roll of the eyes. Sarcasm is often difficult to convey in writing, and it often requires intonation and body language to drive the point home.

Sometimes sarcasm can be more direct

> Liars are the most trustworthy people, and should always be believed.

Another example: let's say someone has jumped from a roof during a silly stunt, and has broken their leg, and you say

> Oh, congratulations!

I found a video on youtube which explains the concept of sarcasm here, probably better than me as the guy demonstrates how intonation is used: https://youtu.be/JHq__pQ82ZI

Comment: [Poe's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law) - your examples, said w/o intonation, is someone *being facetious*. If the speaker is a liar, then it's *irony*.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not sarcasm.

Sarcasm is when you mean the opposite of what you say, and it's negative or hurtful towards someone.

In your example sentence, although sending that message to someone may be rude, insulting or hurtful, you mean those words, not the opposite, so it's not sarcastic.

A sarcastic version of that sentence might be:

> Always lie to people who trust you; always trust people who lie to you

This is sarcastic because the intended meaning is opposite to what the words say.

Comment: But sending this quote will be rude to only those people whom you know lie? Or this quote sounds rude? Are there any particular category of sentences which can convey the meaning in a witty way and not be rude. So like in this quote, I intentionally wanted to make the other person realize that they are untruthful. Also, it's just a quote; it depends upon how the other person receives it

Comment: @rohit: If you're calling the other person a liar, directly or indirectly, it's rude. Perhaps necessary rudeness, but you can't insult someone without it being rude on some level, however much you try to disguise it. It's context-dependent; if the person it's delivered to perceives it as a rebuke, you're rude. If you're not trying to rebuke anyone, the context determines whether what you sent makes any sense without an implied rebuke.